# compat_ioctl not working properly for unsigned long long data type

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am learning ioctl functionality in device drivers,

There is a function pointer .compat_ioctl in file_operations which allows 32-bit processes to use ioctls in 64-bit machines.

Following is my Driver Code:

```
#ifndef __IOCTL_CMD_H
#define __IOCTL_CMD_H

#define MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER    0x21

#define MSG_IOCTL_GET_LENGTH    _IOR(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 1, unsigned int)

#define MSG_IOCTL_CLEAR_BUFFER  _IO(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 2)

#define MSG_IOCTL_FILL_BUFFER   _IOW(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 3, unsigned char)

#define MSG_GET_ADDRESS     _IOR(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 4, unsigned long)

#define MSG_IOCTL_MAX_CMDS      4

#endif


long device_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    unsigned char ch;
    int retval = 0;
    long size = _IOC_SIZE(cmd);

    pr_info("%s: Cmd:%u\t Arg:%lu Size:%lu add:%p\n", __func__, cmd, arg, size, &ch);

    if (_IOC_TYPE(cmd) != MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER) return -ENOTTY;
    if (_IOC_NR(cmd) > MSG_IOCTL_MAX_CMDS) return -ENOTTY;

    //access_ok is kernel-oriented, so the concept of read and write is reversed

    retval = access_ok((void __user *)arg, size);

    pr_info("access_ok returned:%d\n", retval);
    if (!retval)
        return -EFAULT;

    switch(cmd)
    {
        //Get Length of buffer
        case MSG_IOCTL_GET_LENGTH:
            pr_info("Get Buffer Length\n");
            put_user(MAX_SIZE, (unsigned int *)arg);
            break;
        //clear buffer
        case MSG_IOCTL_CLEAR_BUFFER:
            pr_info("Clear buffer\n");
            memset(kernel_buffer, 0, sizeof(kernel_buffer));
            break;
        //fill character
        case MSG_IOCTL_FILL_BUFFER:
            get_user(ch, (unsigned char *)arg);
            pr_info("Fill Character:%c\n", ch);
            memset(kernel_buffer, ch, sizeof(kernel_buffer));
            buffer_index = sizeof(kernel_buffer);
            break;
        //address of kernel buffer
        case MSG_GET_ADDRESS:
            put_user(0x12345678, (unsigned long*)arg);
            pr_info("MSG_GET_ADDRESS\n");
            break;
        default:
            pr_info("Unknown Command:%u\n", cmd);
            return -ENOTTY;
    }
    return 0;
}


long device_compat_ioctl(struct file *filp, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    unsigned char ch;
    int retval = 0;
    long size = _IOC_SIZE(cmd);

    pr_info("%s: Cmd:%u\t Arg:%lu Size:%lu add:%p\n", __func__, cmd, arg, size, &ch);

    if (_IOC_TYPE(cmd) != MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER) return -ENOTTY;
    if (_IOC_NR(cmd) > MSG_IOCTL_MAX_CMDS) return -ENOTTY;

    //access_ok is kernel-oriented, so the concept of read and write is reversed

    retval = access_ok((void __user *)arg, size);

    pr_info("access_ok returned:%d\n", retval);
    if (!retval)
        return -EFAULT;

    switch(cmd)
    {
        //Get Length of buffer
        case MSG_IOCTL_GET_LENGTH:
            pr_info("Get Buffer Length\n");
            put_user(MAX_SIZE, (unsigned int *)arg);
            break;
        //clear buffer
        case MSG_IOCTL_CLEAR_BUFFER:
            pr_info("Clear buffer\n");
            memset(kernel_buffer, 0, sizeof(kernel_buffer));
            break;
        //fill character
        case MSG_IOCTL_FILL_BUFFER:
            get_user(ch, (unsigned char *)arg);
            pr_info("Fill Character:%c\n", ch);
            memset(kernel_buffer, ch, sizeof(kernel_buffer));
            buffer_index = sizeof(kernel_buffer);
            break;
        //address of kernel buffer
        case MSG_GET_ADDRESS:
            put_user(0x12345678, (unsigned long*)arg);
            pr_info("MSG_GET_ADDRESS\n");
            break;
        default:
            pr_info("Unknown Command:%u\n", cmd);
            return -ENOTTY;
    }
    return 0;
}




struct file_operations device_fops = {
    .read = device_read,
    .write = device_write,
    .open = device_open,
    .release = device_release,
    .llseek = device_lseek,
    .unlocked_ioctl = device_ioctl,
    .compat_ioctl = device_compat_ioctl
};
```

MSG_GET_ADDRESS ioctl accepts unsigned long long which is 4 bytes in 32 bit process and 8 bytes in 64 bit process. That is the reason i wrote compat_ioctl.

When i call the below code from user space (32-bit process), it fails with unknown ioctl in compat_ioctl definition.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char buffer[1024];  
    int fd;
    unsigned int length;
    int i = 0;
    unsigned long addr;

    fd = open("/dev/msg", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("fd failed");
        exit(2);
    }

    printf("Size:%d\n", _IOC_SIZE(MSG_GET_ADDRESS));
    printf("cmd:%u\n", MSG_GET_ADDRESS);

    ioctl(fd, MSG_GET_ADDRESS, &addr);
    perror("ioctl");
    getchar();
    printf("address:%x\n", addr);

    close(fd);
}
```

What is the mistake i am making here.

Comment: `unsigned long long` is always 64 bit.

Comment: You should call `ret = ioctl(); if (ret < 0) perror();`.

Comment: It seems that the number which the user program passes as ioctl identificator does **not match** the one in the kernel. I see you have `pr_info` in the kernel; what is output of it when the user program works?

Comment: Yes the number are not same in both cases 32-bit/64-bit. How to deal in such scenario. Do we need to create a new ioctl command code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` ioctl request code is defined as:

```
#define MSG_GET_ADDRESS _IOR(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 4, unsigned long)
```

The size of the third parameter is encoded into the ioctl request code.  The size can be extracted from the request code using the `_IOC_SIZE(req)` macro.

The numeric value of `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` will be different in a 32-bit process/kernel compared to a 64-bit process/kernel. In particular, the encoded size will be different.

On a 32-bit process/kernel, `_IOC_SIZE(MSG_GET_ADDRESS)` will be 4. On a 64-bit process/kernel, `_IOC_SIZE(MSG_GET_ADDRESS)` will be 8. This is due to the different `sizeof(unsigned long)` values on 32-bit and 64-bit systems.

When running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit kernel with 32-bit compatibility support, the 32-bit process will be calling `ioctl()` with the 32-bit version of the `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` request code. However, your driver's `device_compat_ioctl()`  is looking for the 64-bit version of the `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` request code.

A solution is to define a 32-bit version of the ioctl request code in the driver to mirror the "official" `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` request code:

```
#define MSG32_GET_ADDRESS _IOR(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 4, compat_ulong_t)
```

Note that this request code does not need to be in the user-mode headers as it is only for use in kernel mode. However, if it is more convenient, you could include it in the user-mode headers but wrapped in a `#ifdef __KERNEL__` / `#endif` pair:

```
#ifdef __KERNEL__
#define MSG32_GET_ADDRESS _IOR(MSG_MAGIC_NUMBER, 4, compat_ulong_t)
#endif
```

Now, your `device_compat_ioctl` function should be changed to handle a `MSG32_GET_ADDRESS` request code instead of a `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` request code:

```
        //address of kernel buffer
        case MSG32_GET_ADDRESS:
            put_user(0x12345678, (compat_ulong_t*)arg);
            pr_info("MSG_GET_ADDRESS\n");
            break;
```

**Note:** According to the comments in your code, the `MSG_GET_ADDRESS` is actually supposed to get the address of a kernel buffer. I don't know what your user-space code intends to do with it, but be aware that a 64-bit kernel address will not fit in a 32-bit `unsigned long` (or the 32-bit `compat_ulong_t` type).